# run macro on time in excel visual basic

Tags: excel, vba, timer

Have excel visual basic timer setup like this:

```
Sub requestHistoricalData()
Dim alertTime As String
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
MsgBox Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Application.OnTime alertTime, "!requestHistoricalData"
End Sub
```

When I run the macro requestHistoricalData the MsbBox works but the error that comes up for the timer is:

```
 Cannot run the macro 'requestHistoricalData.' The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

I made sure macros trust developer mode in the trust settings.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't use a variable with the `OnTime` function like this, but `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "!requestHistoricalData"` works fine.

Comment: Having thought this through a bit, here's the error message I get when I run your macro as is, `Method 'OnTime' of object '_Application' failed`.  If you change the definition of `alertTime` from `String` to `Date` then this error goes away.

Comment: Which module is this code in?

Comment: None of these comments helped.